# How to avoid Sql Injection for PHP Yii2 framework inside the andFilterWhere function

Tags: php, sql, yii2, sql-injection

I am new to PHP and Yii2 framework, I believe there should be some way similar to their official doc but I could not find out. Please see the code.

```
$query = new Query(). 
$query->andFilterWhere(
                        [
                            'like',
                            LiveListData::tableName() . '.originalRoamerRequestId',
                            $pattern
                        ]
                    );
```

I want to escape the $pattern variable because that is an user input. Could any please tell me how should I do that please? Their official doc provides an example, but I cannot get any clue from there.

Below is their docs

```
$userIDs = (new Query())
->select('id')
->from('user')
->where('status=:status', [':status' => $status])
->all();
```

Your help will be much appreciated

Comment: You don't need to escape `$pattern`. If you use `andFilterWhere()` in this way, Yii will already escape wildcards and use parameterized queries to avoid SQLI.

Comment: the only u should avoid is `%` → `\%` and `_` → `\_`